# If I ignore SSL certificate verification, data is still encrypted?

Tags: python, https, ssl-certificate, urllib2

In this python code

```
import urllib2
import ssl

ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

urllib2.urlopen("https://your-test-server.local", context=ctx)
```

I can ignore SSL Certificate validation, but in this case data is still encrypted?

Answer (score 1):

The short version: the data will be encrypted, but the connection might be compromised. Don't expect it to be secure!

Comment: Yes I know but I need this for a https connection to my own rest server. Since I'm the only user and I preferer to not spend money for a ssl certificate :)
Tx for reply

Comment: Doesn't do any difference. Without trusted CA certificate a man-in-the-middle attack can be performed easily. But you have the option to create your own little certificate authority (for example with gnomint) or use a free certificate service like CAcert or do manually with OpenSSL, there are several tutorial on the net.

Comment: I tryed to make my own certificate with openssl but when I try to connect via https without ignore certificate validation I get the same error, about certificate is not trusted.